# Error in for loop - attempt to select less than one element in integerOneIndex

Tags: r, c, for-loop, vector

I'm trying to translate a C routine from an old sound synthesis program into R, but have indexing issues which I'm struggling to understand (I'm a beginner when it comes to using loops).

The routine creates an exponential lookup table - the vector `exptab`:

```
# Define parameters
sinetabsize <- 8192
prop <- 0.8
BP <- 10
BD <- -5
BA <- -1 

# Create output vector
exptab <- vector("double", sinetabsize)

# Loop
while(abs(BD) > 0.00001){
  BY = (exp(BP) -1) / (exp(BP*prop)-1)
  if (BY > 2){
    BS = -1
  }
  else{
    BS = 1
  }
  if (BA != BS){
    BD = BD * -0.5
    BA = BS
    BP = BP + BD
  }
  if (BP <= 0){
    BP = 0.001
  }
  BQ = 1 / (exp(BP) - 1)
  incr = 1 / sinetabsize
  x = 0
  stabsize = sinetabsize + 1
  for (i in (1:(stabsize-1))){
  x = x + incr
  exptab [[sinetabsize-i]] = 1 - (BQ * (exp(BP * x) - 1))
  }
}
```

Running the code gives the error:

```
Error in exptab[[sinetabsize - i]] <- 1 - (BQ * (exp(BP * x) - 1)) : 
  attempt to select less than one element in integerOneIndex
```

Which, I understand from looking at other posts, indicates an indexing problem. But, I'm finding it difficult to work out the exact issue.

I suspect the error may lie in my translation. The original C code for the last few lines is:

```
for (i=1; i < stabsize;i++){
  x += incr;
  exptab[sinetabsize-i] =  1.0 - (float) (BQ*(exp(BP*x) - 1.0));
}
```

I had thought the R code `for (i in (1:(stabsize-1)))` was equivalent to the C code `for (i=1; i< stabsize;i++)` (i.e. the initial value of i is `i = 1`, the test is whether `i < stabsize`, and the increment is +1). But now I'm not so sure.

Any suggestions as to where I'm going wrong would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

As you say, array indexing in R starts at 1.  In C it starts at zero.  I reckon that's your problem.  Can `sinetabsize-i` ever get to zero?

Comment: Ah, got it. The no. of elements in the `exptab` array is the same as `sinetabsize`, so when `i = 8192`, `sinetabsize - i = 0`. Where would be the best place to compensate for this?

Comment: :)  Yup!  [Been there, worn that t-shirt many times...]  It looks like you're filling `exptab` from the end back to the beginning.  So would simply `exptab [[sinetabsize]] = 1 - (BQ * (exp(BP * x) - 1))` do the trick?  But you know your code better than I do and the relationships between the other variables don't seem obvious.  Try it.  if it works, check it.  Then check it again.  Repeat until comfortable.  Can you run the code with a smaller initial value of `sinetabsize'?  No more than 10, say?

Comment: Hehe - thanks. Glad I'm not alone... :) `sinetabsize` is the length of a matching sine lookup table (i.e. matching the exponential lookup table `exptab`), so it has to stay at that value. I've tried a few things that appear to fill the vector correctly (e.g. changing the for test to `i in sinetabsize:1`, along with using `exptab[[i]]`, rather than `exptab[[sinetabsize-1]]`) but these seem to result in a neverending loop that I have to interrupt R to stop. Do you have any idea why that would be?